# Alabama is not showing on my map

Tags: d3.js

Here's a puzzler. After adding the legend scale code the state of Alabama is not showing up on the US map. Like so:

[image: missing alabama]

I've narrowed it down to the `g.call(xAxis)` at the end which seems to be the problem. When I comment it out, Alabama shows on the map. Like here:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something? Here's the code.

```
<script>
var w = 800;
var h = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#us-map")       
        .append('svg')
        .attr('w',w+'px')
        .attr('h',h+'px');

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
.translate([w/2,h/2])
.scale(1000) 

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

///////////////////// /legend  

var color = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([75, 150, 225, 300])
  .range(["#ffffcc", "#c2e699", "#78c679", "#31a354", "#006837"]);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, 390])
.range([0, 240]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickSize(13)
.tickValues(color.domain());

var g = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "key")
.attr("transform", "translate(40,40)");

g.selectAll("rect")
.data(color.range().map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    x0: i ? x(color.domain()[i - 1]) : x.range()[0],
    x1: i < color.domain().length ? x(color.domain()[i]) : x.range()[1],
    z: d
  };
 }))
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("height", 8)
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0; })
.attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.z; });

g.call(xAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("class", "caption")
.attr("y", -6)
.text("Population per square mile");


d3.csv("expenses.csv", function(data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {   
d.value = +d.value; 
  });
            color.domain([
            d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }),
            d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value })
    ]);

 d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) { 

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var dataState = data[i].state;
         var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].value);

          for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
       var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;    
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
            json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;      
            break;              
        }
    }       
 }

 svg.selectAll("path")
     .data(json.features)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)
     .style("stroke","#ccc")
     .style("fill", function(d) {

 var value = d.properties.value;                            
    if (value) {
        return color(value);
    } else {
       return "#000";
                       }
 })

     });
});

</script>
```

Comment: left field comment.  Alabama is often the first state in a list based on its alphabetical full name or its FIPS federal id of "01".   Think about zero based indexes and loop iterators.  Just the first thing that comes to mind for what its worth.

Comment: Thanks. But does the g.call(xAxis) use a loop? Otherwise it works fine when this line is not there. I am using the code from here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5737662

Comment: What does expenses.csv look like?

Comment: This is the csv file state,year,value
     New York,2014,2500
     Georgia,2014,2900
     Illinois,2014,1450
     New Jersey,2014,210
     Tennessee,2014,800
     Florida,2014,1230
     Maine,2014,130
     Ohio,2014,2100

Comment: This is totally a kludge but following @SqlSurfer 's hint I added a shape to the beginning of my topojson geometries without any arcs or properties and it fixed this issue. I don't  know how an array index issue comes into play but it seems to be the problem.